# Is there a python function for seeded white noise?

Tags: python, procedural-generation, whitenoise

I have been working on some python terrain generation software, and have been wanting to generate cave systems. I need a seeded white noise function/module that works over an infinite terrain, and accepts floating point number inputs.

I found out how to generate perlin worms, and that went fine. My problem was generating them over an infinite terrain. I have looked all over Stack Overflow, and found two functions: one that only accepted integers, and one that was in GLSL that I could not figure out how to translate into python.

Thanks in advance, I've been trying to get this to work for a while.

Comment: What's the rationale behind seeding it with a float vs an integer?

Comment: I think you have to be much more specific.  all pseudo RNGs start from a seed, and generally output uniformly distributed integer values.  how you turn your "seed" into something that's valid for the RNG or transform the output is up to you

Comment: The terrain is generated in chunks, each with an area of 1. the player, however, can move around within the chunks. The main reason was so that I had the option to get the most specific coordinate possible for later development. But I will just change the proportions for now, unless there is some way to get it with floats.

Comment: Maybe multiply your float by 10^something and then truncate it to turn it into an int. Or, `hash` your float (which turns it into an integer) and use that?

Comment: Perfect, `hash` worked great. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `random` module is a built-in solution for this.  Here is a simple implementation of additive Gaussian white noise with a seed value of `1234`.  Assuming you have a list of data points to make noisy, this is a reasonable way to go.

```py
import random

random.seed(a=1234)

for item in mydata:
   item += random.gauss(0.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: This works better than `hash` because it is faster and simpler.